# A question about JavaScript's TypeError exception

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, typeerror

I've 3 questions. Thank you!

First question:

When will JavaScript codes cause a "TypeError" exception?

Other questions:

I've codes below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>An HTML5 document</title>
<script>
    var str = 'abc'; // str's type is string, not object

    // Syntax: Object.getPrototypeOf(object)
    alert(Object.getPrototypeOf(str)); // Uncaught TypeError: Object.getPrototypeOf called on non-object

    // Syntax: prototype.isPrototypeOf(object)
    if (Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(str)) { // false
        alert('true');
    } else {
        alert('false');
    }
</script>
```

Method `getPrototypeOf()` and `isPrototypeOf()` are both need a parameter which type should be object. And `str`'s type is string.

Why `getPrototypeOf` method throws an TypeError exception, and `isPrototypeOf` method doesn't throws any errors?

If `str`'s type is object (`var str = new String('abc')`), the result of `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(str)` is `true`. But the result of codes above is `false`. Why isn't `str` converted from string to object automatically when it's used as a parameter of `isPrototypeOf` method?

Thank you!

Comment: you should construct your "str" string via the String constructor (str = new String('abc') ) so that you don't get a TypeError.I agree.. it is a bit odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take a look at the first hit for ["TypeError mdc"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError). When it throws a typeerror is upto the specification and the user.

The other answeres the specific question.

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that `isPrototypeOf` is kind of like the brother to the `instanceof` operator so they really should have the same basic semantics. Also new functions in ECMAScript 5 tend to be a bit more strict when compared to functions in older editions. Here are the algorithms used.

```
15.2.3.2  Object.getPrototypeOf ( O ) 

When the getPrototypeOf function is called with argument O, 
the following steps are taken: 

1.  If Type(O) is not Object throw a TypeError exception. 
2.  Return the value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of O. 

15.2.4.6  Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf (V) 

When the isPrototypeOf method is called with argument V, 
the following steps are taken: 

1.  If V is not an object, return false. 
2.  Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as 
    the argument.  
3.  Repeat 
  a.  Let V be the value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of V. 
  b.  if V is null, return false 
  c.  If O and V refer to the same object, return true.
```